# Registration form error?

Tags: php, registration

I've created a registration form, and a login form for my website. Everything works fine, except this: When trying to login in to my website, I have to enter the encrypted password, not the one I actually typed in. i have the registration form salted and everything, so I would I make it so the user can log in with the password he actually typed in? 
thanks

Register.php

```
<?php
include 'header inc.php';
$error = "";
if (@$_POST['register']) {
 $firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
 $lastname = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
 $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $password1 = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
 $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['passwordrepeat']);

 $day = strip_tags($_POST['day']);
 $month = strip_tags($_POST['month']);
 $year = strip_tags($_POST['year']);
 $dob = "$day/$month/$year";

 if ($firstname == '') {
  echo "Firstname cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($lastname == '') {
  echo "Lastname cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($username == '') {
  echo  "Username cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($email == '') {
  echo  "Email cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($password1 == '') {
  echo  "Password cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($password2 == '') {
  echo "Repeat Password cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($day == '') {
  echo "The day you were born cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($month == '') {
  echo "The month you were born cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else if ($year == '') {
  echo "The year you were born cannot be left empty.";
 }
 else {
 //Check the username doesn't already exist
 $check_username = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
 $numrows_username = mysql_num_rows($check_username);
 if ($numrows_username != 0) {
  echo 'That username has already been registered.';
 }
 else
 {
  $check_email = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $numrows_email = mysql_num_rows($check_email);
 if ($numrows_email != 0) {
  $error = 'That email has already been registered.';
 }
 else
 {
   $salt1 = "francis";
   $salt1 = md5($salt1);
   $salt2 = "cookie";
   $salt2 = md5($salt2);
   $salt3 = "php";
   $salt3 = md5($salt3);
   $password1 = $salt1.$password1.$salt3;
   $password1 = md5($password1.$salt2);
   $password2 = $salt1.$password2.$salt3;
   $password2 = md5($password2.$salt2);
 if ($password1 != $password2) {
 $error = 'The passwords don\'t match!';
 }
 else
 {
 //Register the user
 $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$email','$password1','$dob','no')");
 die('Regsitered successfully!');
 }
 }
 }
}
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h2 style="color:#848484;">Create Your Account</h2>
<form action='join.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='firstname'  onclick='value="" ' id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='lastname'  onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='username'onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='email' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='password' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='passwordrepeat' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />
<input type='text' name='day' value='' size='3' maxlength='2' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/>
<input type='text' name='month' value='' size='6' maxlength='2' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/>
<input type='text' name='year' value='' size='4' maxlength='4' onclick='value=""'id='username1'/><p />

<input type='submit' name='register' value='Create Your Account'id='submit1' />
<?php echo $error; ?>
</form>

</body>
```

Login.php

```
    <?php
include ( 'header inc.php' );
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&($_POST['password'])) {
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
 $check_username = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check_username);
 if ($numrows != 1) {
  echo 'That User doesn\'t exist.';
 }
 else
 {
  $check_password = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE password='$password' && username='$username'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_password)) {
   $password_db = $row['password'];

   if ($password_db == $password) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: template.php");
   }
  }
 }
}

?>



<h2 style="color:#848484;">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspLogin to Your Account</h2>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type='text' name='username'  id="username1"/><p />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type='password' name='password' id="username1"/><p />

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login to my Account' id="submit1" />
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Let's see... sql injection vulnerabilities, invalid html entities, use of `@` error suppression, failure to re-hash the password entered into the login form, use of deprecated/obsolete mysql library... shall I go on?

Comment: 1) Do you understand *why* you're hashing the password? 2) You need to hash the entered password and compare it to the hash in the database for verification. 3) You're doing salting wrong, you need to use a random salt for each password. 4) MD5 is broken for password hashing. 5) Use PHP's password hashing functions: http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: how code i fix all of this/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the password salted and md5 in the db therefore when you pull it out of the db it will still be that way. You need to do the same thing to the password you are checking it against.

```
$salt1 = "francis";
$salt1 = md5($salt1);
$salt2 = "cookie";
$salt2 = md5($salt2);
$salt3 = "php";
$salt3 = md5($salt3);
$password1 = $salt1.$password.$salt3;
$password1 = md5($password1.$salt2); 
if ($password_db == $password1) {
    //code
}
```

But read comments above you have some other major issues.